# fopen() always returns NULL

Tags: c

```c
int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *list,*file;
    char temp[30];
    list=fopen("filelist","rb");
    while(fgets(temp,30,list)!=NULL)
    {
        file=fopen(temp,"r");
    {
    fclose(list);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code I basically want to open all files in filelist but my fopen call (exept the first one always returns a NULL am i missing something also this is my filelist

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

also i dont use file extensions and files exist in the same directory wtih executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) stores the new-line character into the buffer it is populating so you need to remove it before calling `fopen()` within the `while`.

From the linked reference page for `fgets()`:

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. The produced character string is always NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or **a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character**.

Example code to remove the new-line:

```
char* nl = strrchr(temp, '\n');
if (nl)  *nl = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets`  leaves the newline on the end of the string, which you can plainly see if you add the following line afterwards:

```
printf ("[%s]\n", temp);
```

You'll see something like:

```
[file1
]
```

You need to remove it before use, which you can do this with something like:

```
size_t sz = strlen (temp);
if (sz > 0)
    if (temp[sz-1] == '\n')
        temp[sz-1] = '\0';
```

---

You can see this effect in action in the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    size_t sz;
    char temp[30];

    printf ("\n> ");
    while (fgets (temp, sizeof(temp), stdin) != NULL) {
        printf ("before: [%s]\n", temp);
        sz = strlen (temp);
        if (sz > 0) {
            if (temp[sz-1] == '\n') {
                temp[sz-1] = '\0';
            }
        }
        printf ("after : [%s]\n", temp);
        printf ("\n> ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It basically uses your exact method to get a line using `fgets` (but from standard input) and then outputs the result both before and after removal of the trailing newline. A sample run follows:

```
pax> ./testprog

> hello
before: [hello
]
after : [hello]

> goodbye
before: [goodbye
]
after : [goodbye]

> [CTRL-D]

pax> _
```

---

You may also want to look at a few other things in that code segment:

- the use of an open brace `{` at the end of the `while` loop.
- the fact that you're opening the files within the loop and not doing anything with them (including closing them).
- the use of `"rb"` open mode. Usually this is unnecessary, it's *certainly* unnecessary if you know it's a text file.
- you should *always* check the return codes of functions that can fail (like `fopen`) before using them.
- the canonical form of `main` in C where no arguments are needed is `int main (void)`.

Comment: Might want to look for `\r` also.

Comment: i think \r gets erased by compiler for text files

Comment: @mah, that's only going to be an issue if you're mixing file formats (such as DOS and UNIX), unlikely if you're doing all your work on the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I'll state my case of which I am still uncertain: I thought my problem was with "fopen", but after trying every single solution, I ran into the extension problem, which I'm facing in Windows 10. It appears that Windows puts ".txt" automatically but, if you put ".txt" as extension, the name becomes ".txt.txt" at the end. So I left the file name with no extension, and put "file.txt" as argument of "fopen", and that was the only way it has worked for me.